# MATLAB - Maximum likelihood for periodic function (angles)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, matlab

In the MATLAB stats tutorials there is a section called *"Fitting a More Complicated Distribution: A Mixture of Two Normals"*
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-custom-univariate-distributions.html

```
pdf_normmixture = @(x,p,mu1,mu2,sigma1,sigma2) ...
                     p*normpdf(x,mu1,sigma1) + (1-p)*normpdf(x,mu2,sigma2);
lb = [0 -Inf -Inf 0 0];
ub = [1 Inf Inf Inf Inf];
start = [pStart muStart sigmaStart sigmaStart];
paramEsts = mle(x, 'pdf',pdf_normmixture, 'start',start, 'lower',lb, 'upper',ub)
```

It uses MLE to estimate numerically the values

"    [...] = MLE(DATA,'pdf',PDF,'cdf',CDF,'start',START,...) returns MLEs
for the parameters of the distribution defined by the probability
density and cumulative distribution functions PDF and CDF.  PDF and CDF
are function handles created using @.  They accept as inputs a vector
of data and one or more individual distribution parameters, and return
vectors of probability density values and cumulative probability
values, respectively.  If the 'censoring' name/value pair is not
present, you may omit the 'cdf' name/value pair.  MLE computes the
estimates by numerically maximizing the distribution's log-likelihood,
and START is a vector containing initial values for the parameters."

I would like to apply the same methodology for fitting two or more normals to a univariate set of values that I have, but **within a periodic domain**. That is, angles that have values of 0° to 360° linked together as a circular range. I am not sure how to declare it in order to make MATLAB understand this kind of terminology.

Would it be possible to change this implementation to add the circular range case?

Comment: I have implemented a statistical test to compare the cumulative distribution of my data and the fitted function that I have predicted. It is not urgent to answer this question, but if someone wants to be creative any comments are welcomed